# How to refresh dijit/form/Select's store in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, select, store, dojo

I get a problem when I's attempting to refresh dijit/form/Select's store and to reload the data from back-end, here is my way to create dijit/form/Select:

```
var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({url: CONTEXT + "user/doListUsers.action"});

var selector = new Select({
    store: store,
    name: "userId",
    required: true,
    missingMessage: "You should select a user.",
    style: {
        width: "250px"
    },
    maxHeight: 300
}, "user_select");

selector.startup();
```

And then I need to refresh selector's store to keep selecting users are new, and I follow Dojo official's doc http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#id3 to do this like below ways:

```
if (store) {
    store.close();
    store.fetch();
}
```

or

```
if (store) {
    store.url = CONTEXT + "user/doListUsers.action";
    store.close();
}
```

Both above methods don't work, I didn't see a AJAX request posting to back-end when I execute them. So how can I make select to reload data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well I know I'm not offering a solution, but to begin with I would recommend changing to a non-deprecated api, such as [JsonRest](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) with a [Cache](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/Cache.html) and [Memory](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/Memory.html) store. You may find it handles your use case better.

Comment: I agree with Jez, take a look at this blog post: SitePen.com [Dojo Object Stores > Observing Data Updates: dojo/store/Observable](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/02/15/dojo-object-stores/). Example shows how to use Observable to listen for changes in your [store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/Cache.html).

Comment: Yes wrapping your Memory stores with Observable would be a good idea, it is really simple to set up a query on your store and pick up changes to its result set.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved simillar problem myself by an ugly hack:

```
function fetch_select_data(select){
    var store = select.store;
    select.setStore(store);
}
```

In my case I use JsonRestStore to fetch data from backend and I suggest you to do the same.

Comment: Thanks!! `select.setStore(new_store) worked`. I was trying to use `select.store = new_store` all this time and it wasn't updating the options in select.